# Is it possible to evaluate $f(5)$ from given function?

Tags: functions

> Given that
>   $$ f(x^2+x)=4x^2+4x−3 $$
>   Is it possible to evaluate  $f(5)$ from given function?

Regards

Comment: Your function is $f(y)=4y-3$ for $y=x^2+x$.

Comment: Any thoughts?  You've asked a lot of very similar questions in the past couple of hours...maybe you can use some of the answers you've been given to solve the similar problems?

Comment: @lulu thank you for making me aware of this. I will not answer any more questions of the same type from OP

Answer (score 6):

Note that $$f(x^2+x) = 4(x^2+x)-3$$

Let $x^2+x=5$ then $$f(5) = 4(5)-3 = 20-3 =17$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$ f(x^2+x)=4x^2+4x−3 \to f(x^2+x)=4\cdot(x^2+x)−3$$So, over all non-negative $y$, this function is equivalent to $$f(y)=4y-3$$

Comment: +1,for your simplicity ....

Answer (score 0):

as $$x^2+x=5$$
$$\implies,x=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{21}}{2} or,-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{21}}{2} $$
if you substitute the value of $x$ in the function then in every time you will get,
$$f(5)=17$$

Comment: Sure, you could do this, but I feel like the point of the problem is to exploit the obvious symmetry in the function.

Comment: yes,it could be...